# Securing sensitive data after using std::stringstream

Tags: c++, security

I am creating a command line application to read data sensitive data (like passwords). I do not want such sensitive data remaining in the memory after data processing. For the following code, is there any way to clear content of the std::stringstream object in the way like I cleared string below with the use of memset? Or, is there any better way to read entire line from the console and tokenize it into vector of strings?

```
    static std::string readLine() noexcept
    {
        std::string string;
        std::getline(std::cin, string);
        return string;
    }

    static std::vector<std::string> splitLine(char delimiter = ' ') noexcept
    {
        std::vector<std::string> command;

        std::string string;
        std::stringstream stringStream(readLine());
        while (std::getline(stringStream, string, delimiter)) {
            command.push_back(string);

            // Example data secure
            memset(string.data(), 0, string.size());
        }

        return command;
    }
```

Comment: Security doesn't mean do a bunch of stuff to data. Security means you first have a threat model, find the attack vectors, then ask how to mitigate them. What is your threat model such that you can _read and process_ the password without worry but you are concerned about the password being unsafe in your own memory?

Comment: (1) There is no guarantee that `memset(string.data(), 0, string.size());` has any effect. (2) Even if it worked it's probably too late. (3) If I attach a debugger to your program what are you going to do about it?

Comment: You can remove `memset` if you do `command.push_back(std::move(string));`. There's no sense in the shown code. All data is stored in `command`.

Comment: But you're storing all the "sensitive" data as plaintext in `command` and returning it?

Comment: Security is done by design, not implementation. Don't work with plaintext strings at all. Use hashes, encrypted data whatever but avoid plaintext (for as long as you can). In your code you try to clear the "local stack" variable but you go on pushing the plaintext into command for everybody to see.

Comment: Thank you all for all the invaluable insights. The `command` is later processed when and then cleared. Also returning the command uses `std::move` same as for `readLine()`.

Comment: ...hashes are later used once I determine the command specified. The command may be a password change or any other application specific command.

Comment: ...would it be better to delegate a separate code for handling the special case for password change?